# How do I delete a service key in Bluemix?

Tags: service, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I want to delete a Bluemix service key. The [Adding a service to your application](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/reqnsi.html) topic in the Bluemix documentation provides the following information about deleting a service:

> If you want to add or delete a service credential, use the cf create-service-key or cf delete-service-key commands. When you add a service
>   credential, you can provide service-specific configuration parameters
>   in a valid JSON object inline, or provide a file that contains the
>   JSON object. See the cf help information for detailed command usage.

However, when I attempt to use the create-service-key command, I see the following error message: `cf: 'delete-service-key' is not a registered command.`. How do I delete the service if this command does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf is down level so you need to update the cf version. cf version 6.12.3 includes the command.